# Gitlab MR pipeline to run all regular pipelines

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner

```
stages:
  - format
  - test

formatter:
  stage: format
  only:
      - merge_requests
  script:
    - echo ${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME}
    - ancestor=$(git merge-base origin/${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME} HEAD)
    - "do some formatting for "git-diff -name-only $ancestor HEAD"

unit_test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - "do some test"
```

For example, I have the above .gitlab-ci.yml.

Right now

1. unit-test only runs for the regular commit
2. format only runs for MR.

As https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/ says,
"If you use this feature with merge when pipeline succeeds, pipelines for merge requests take precedence over the other regular pipelines.".

What I want is,

1. Only "test" runs for each commit.
2. Both "test" and "format" runs for MR, and merge can be approve only if both pipeline succeeds.

How may I achieve this?
Another pre-condition is that I want to use "CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME" variable, which is only defined with only:[merge-requests] or any similar sorts.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) instead of only as `only`/`except` are not in active development any more. And with rules your pipeline will look like this:

```
stages:
  - format
  - test

formatter:
  stage: format
  script:
    - echo ${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME}
    - ancestor=$(git merge-base origin/${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME} HEAD)
    - "do some formatting for "git-diff -name-only $ancestor HEAD"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'

unit_test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - "do some test"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
```

`formatter` stage is only run on merge-requests and the `unit_test` stage is run on merge-requests and commits on all branches.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @danielnelz's answer, I suggest you use `workflows` and `rules` to control how the stages should be triggered. ([workflow documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflow))

Using workflow you can control how pipelines should work or be triggered. For instance, consider the following .gitlab-ci.yml code snippet. With the following workflow, when there is no open merge request for the branch, every stage that is related to branches will be triggered, but none of the merge request-related stages will be triggered. Whenever you create a new merge or open a closed one, the merge request pipeline will be triggered. When you add a commit to an open merge request, by default two pipelines (regular branch and merge request pipelines) will be triggered. But, you can disable **duplicate pipelines** by adding

```
- if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS'
      when: never
```

to your workflow. In that case, while the merge request is open, only the merge request-related stages will be triggered. In the following sample, I've provided different types of stages and I hope it can help you to build your own workflow.

```
...

image: ...

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH' # All branches
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"' # Merge requests
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS' # Disable duplicate pipelines
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG' # All tags

stages:
  ...
  - build
  - test
  - code-analysis
  ...

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    ...
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    ...
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'

code-analysis:
  stage: code-analysis
  script:
    ...
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
```

Comment: this workflow thing does **NOT** work, it still runs duplicate pipeline on MR and on branch...gitlab ci gives one headache at times...things that should be straight forward just dont seem to be

Comment: any proof that the workflow code above works? tested and it does not, so wondering how you concluded it works or am i missing something on my end?

Comment: @uberrebu would you let me know what versions of `Gitlab` and `Gitlab Runners` are you testing against? Is it a self-hosted Gitlab instance or you are using gitlab.com?